# The process in which a fluid establishes static equilibrium

Tags: fluid-statics

I understand that in a static fluid there is no shear stress, the pressure at any point varies with depth and is isotropic. I understand decently the mathematics supporting these properties. However, I am a little unsure the actual process in which a fluid establishes such a static condition.

For example, if a stone is thrown into a water container, there will be an initial disturbance in the water body before it reaches a static condition again. Obviously, during the disturbance, there are shear stresses in the water. Also, the pressure is no longer isotropic and might not vary with depth (I am not quite sure about this--correct me if I am wrong).

My question is, at the continuum level, what is an intuitive way to understand how the water body in this example re-establishes its static condition.

Comment: Basically the same way that a solid material re-establishes its static condition after being subjected to an impulsive impact. Disturbances propagate through the material and also much of the energy of the disturbance may be dissipated by the material itself. Eventually the static condition is re-established.

Comment: I would like a description of the motions of the fluid elements during the disturbance and how they interact with one another such that all the shear stresses gradually disappear. Further, I would also like to have a picture of the process in which the pressure at each point re-establish its isotropic property after the disturbance.

Comment: The scope of your question is too large for this forum. What you're asking for is something that would be more appropriate to be answered by a long research paper.

Comment: Thank you. It was not my intention to pick such a complicated question. Actually, your comment surprised me because I always thought that for scientists working in the field of fluid mechanics, seeing a mental picture of fluid motions in their heads and how they interact with one another is of second nature to them. I mean, understanding the math is one thing, but shouldn't physicists be able to picture the process depicted by the maths? I couldn't imagine how one could find a particular area exciting just by understanding the maths alone.

Comment: Maybe someone specializing in fluid mechanics will chime in, but I certainly don't have any intuition about the detailed flow of fluid currents and how they die out with time when, say, a stone or penny is tossed into a pond of water. That's the sort of thing that supercomputers are used to simulate and study. And those supercomputers don't do it by any sort of "intuition" but by simply the brute-force method of considering the fluid to be made up of billions of tiny fluid elements, and then applying F=ma to all of the elements to see how they move from one microsecond to the next microsecond.

Comment: What you are talking about here is solving the Navier Stokes equations for the fluid motion, coupled to  the motion of the rock.  This is not a problem that would be amenable to analytic solution.  The problem would have to be solved numerically.   The Navier Stokes equations are the result of combining the differential force balance on the fluid with the 3D tensorial version of Newton's law of viscosity.